# Siunitx, exponent-to-prefix, square

Tags: siunitx

> ## Update:
>
> `siunitx`is now updated with the feature requested/bug fix, and is available in Tex Live, and it works great.

#### Reason for dragging this question up again

With the answers I got the last time, I felt I was misunderstood, and I understand that I must have not made my point very clear. I will try again to explain myself.

#### Requirements for accepted answer, leading to bounty

I will accept an answer that can show either of these types of answers:

- My input is wrong, and giving some different commands will result in the result I am hoping for.
- My understanding of mathematics is wrong. The result that I am expecting is totally wrong, and show my why.
- `siunitx`has a bug. Should I report it? Is there a quick fix for it?
- Custom-code which gives me the result I am expecting. See below, under **`siunitx` just doesn't do this?**

#### The question itself:

`Siunitx`can turn exponents into prefixes, and does this very nicely for many inputs. However, when giving `\si`-commands with `cubed`,`squared` doesn't work correctly. My example should make this clear now. I might add, that this happens with `cubic`and `squared` too, and I of course understand that `exponent-to-prefix` might be a new feature and that it may takes a lot of work to create a package like this.

#### `Siunitx` just doesn't do this?

As mentioned in some of the answers and comments, `siunitx` is not meant to do this. Well, I think that is misleading, and I think `siunitx`could benefit from this feature a lot. It would make automatic typesetting a lot easier. I have made some script which takes some calculated inputs and gives typesets these with clear, easy to read inputs. This works for all numbers, but not the mentioned `cubed`,`squared`-units. For all of those, I need to edit manually, one by one. Now, if the community all agrees that this feature should *not* go into `siunitx`, then I would like to ask for a custom-solution for this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup
  {
    exponent-to-prefix = true        ,
    round-mode         = places     ,
    round-precision    = 2           ,
    scientific-notation = engineering,
    zero-decimal-to-integer = false,
  }
\begin{document}
\SI{0.01}{\metre}

\SI{0,0001}{\metre}

\SI{0,0001}{\metre\squared} (should print {\SI{100}{\milli\metre\squared}})

\SI{0,0001}{\metre\cubed} (should print {\SI{100}{\centi\metre\squared}})

\SI{5000}{\deci\metre\squared} (should print {\SI{50}{\metre\squared}})
\end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image: example of wrong results]

Also, have a look at these from [Wolfram Alpha(1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100%C2%B5m%5E2&lk=4&num=1) and [Wolfram Alpha(2)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100mm%5E2) :

[image][image]

Comment: A feature that's, at the least, unexpected. `;-)`

Comment: Your example doesn't show any discrepancy in units conversion. All three examples are gives correct example. So, your claim for third line is wrong. Please add example which you mentioned in comment below, this seems show some problem in unit number/unit conversion.

Comment: @Zarko, are you quite sure?

Comment: `siunitx` is for unit typesetting, **not** conversion. As noted in [Marijn's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273381/89497), the `\squared` is interpreted as "add a superscript 2" - it does not modify the way the preceding unit is interpreted. As for `exponent-to-prefix`, this option results in the conversion of the exponent to a prefix (a representation of an exponent). The unit(s) that follow are not considered in this conversion at all. This behavior could probably be clarified in the manual. As presented it is a bit misleading.

Comment: I found discrepancy in conversion ` \SI{5000}{\deci\metre\squared} ` which should give 50 square meters (0,5 are). Given examples in question gives expected result, doesn't it? I will check latter again.

Comment: @Guho, wouldn't this feature improve `siunitx`a lot? It would make automatic typesetting a lot easier. As of now, I have to manually input every input that is `squared`.

Comment: @runartrollet, till to this question I wasn't aware for this capability of `siunitx`. If it exist, it should work properly. So far we bother with  area units.  I do not know, how this is at other. And at this units should be considered only SI units (what `are` and `hectare` aren't). I similar as you always determine units manually.

Comment: I haven't really seen `are` or any other non-si-units in my own calculation, migh be because I've set the `locale`. Will check when I get home, even though it is unrelated to the quiestion at hand.

Comment: agreed with OP. if `\SI{0,0001}{\metre\squared}` syntax produces counter-intuitive `100µm^2` rather than correct `100mm^2` for the reason that `\squared` only means "extend with `^2`" at some point, couldn't there be a `\metrecarre` or `\squaremetre` provided by `siunitx`, or a use of `\squared` as prefix like ``\squared\metre`` to tell the parser the user is really meaning `m^2` ? (or perhaps this is already in `siunitx` ?)

Comment: I don't think it would need a special `\squaremetre`, just checking for `squared`or `square`should be enough(allthough it would be more difficult for units such as `\pascal\per\square\metre`as then it wouldn't really apply. It is perhaps a difficult feature to implement, but it should be doable.

Comment: Note that the 'transformations' here were only every really intended for simple cases: metres to centimetres, _etc._, and that I've simply not tried to cover more complex cases. I will take a look at the code and see if I can extend readily to powers of one unit, but note that I'm _not_ going to take on more complex units (`\centi\metre\per\kilo\gram` or whatever).

Comment: Thank you @JosephWright, this is great news. Really awesome work on this package, I absolutely love it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exponent-to-prefix conversion is quite 'simple minded' and is meant for easy-to-handle cases. Initially that meant that the behaviour with power in units was undefined. However, it is simple to extend the conversion code for the case

```
\SI{0.001}{\metre\squared}
```

or similar. This has therefore been done and will be present in v2.6o onward (sent to CTAN 2016-01-05).

Comment: great work, and really fast. I will have a look at it as soon as it is available.

Answer (score 6):

`siunitx` just provides `\squared` as a notation macro, not a computation.
So 0,0001 metre is (correctly) converted to 100 micrometre and the square symbol is added, resulting in 100 μm². Cf.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[per-mode=fraction]{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3
\begin{document}
\SI{5}{\metre\squared}
\end{document}
```

which gives 5m² (and not 25m²).

Comment: With exponent-to-prefix one would think that it should pay attention to whether the number is squared or cubed. Currently, exponent-to-prefix works great for any other number.

Comment: I might not be clear enough. 5m² is of course not 25m², but it is 5000dm². For the example 5m², it should give 5m², but if you gave it 5000dm² as inputCurrently, Siunitx makes errors when converting these. currently, for     \SI{5000}{\deci\metre\squared}  it gives 5 hm², which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform a calculation (e.g., squaring a number) along with printing it out in a formatted manner, you may achieve your objective by using LuaLaTeX. (The result should be `10 nm`, right?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3
\sisetup
  { per-mode           = fraction    ,
    exponent-to-prefix = true        ,
    round-mode         = places      ,
    round-precision    = 2           ,
    scientific-notation = engineering,
    zero-decimal-to-integer = true
  }

\begin{document}
\SI{\directlua{tex.sprint(0.0001^2)}}{\metre\squared} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actaully, it should output 100mm². And, is this not a bug in siunitx? I mean, it should be able to convert these numbers correctly, if it can do normal numbers which are not squared. 1m = 1000mm, 1m² ≠ 1000Mmm² but 1000000mm^2